# Given the sum of 100 positive integers, calculate maximum of sum of triple products

Tags: number-theory, inequality

The sum of 100 positive integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{100} $ is $2007$. Calculate the maximum possible value of

$$\sum_{1 \le i < j < k \le 100} a_ia_ja_k$$

My thoughts are around AM>GM>HM. Taking GM of 3 terms at a time, doing so gives me cubes on other side, not sure how to simplify that.
Informally speaking I tried to estimate the answer by splitting 2007 into 100 components very close to one another wherein I get 1307223995

Comment: What have you tried ? What are your thoughts on the question ?

Comment: @SacAndSac updated  my thoughts

Comment: By [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality), the sum is less than $\left\lfloor \binom{100}{3}\left(\frac{2007}{100}\right)^3\right\rfloor = 1307230395$, what you have (in previous edit) looks pretty close to optimal (if not the optimal one)

Comment: The way you wrote it suggests that $\sum a_ia_ja_k = (\sum a_i)^3 = 2007^3$

Comment: @achille-hui yes without knowing about Maclaurin's inequality I approximated that plugging in 20.07 for each number  but trying to find integer solutions I could manage something slightly smaller than this trying combinations of 20s and 21s.

Comment: @Salcio updated. let me know if that's correct way.

Comment: Nope, I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1307223995$ is indeed the maximum.

Let $\;e_3 = \!\!\sum\limits_{1\le i < j < k\le 100} a_i a_j a_k\;$ be the sum at hand.

Let $\;p_\ell = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{100} a_k^\ell\;$ for $\ell = 0,1,2,3$. we have $p_0 = 100$ and $p_1 = 2007$.

Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums), we can express $e_3$ in terms of $p_\ell$:

$$6 e_3 = p_1^3 - 3p_1p_2 + 2p_3$$

Notice for integer $x$ satisfies $1 \le x \le 2007$, we have

$$(x-20)(x-21) \ge 0\quad\text{ and }\quad5939-2x \ge 0$$
This implies
$$\begin{align} & (x-20)(x-21)(5939 - 2x) \ge 0\\
\iff & -2x^3 + 6021 x^2 - 244339 x + 2494380 \ge 0\\
\iff & -3p_1 x^2 + 2x^3 \le -244339 x + 2494380
\end{align}
$$
Replace $x$ by $a_k$ and sum over $k$, we obtain
$$-3p_1p_2 + 2p_3 \le -244339 p_1 + 2494380 p_0$$
As a result,

$$e_3 \le \frac16\left(2007^3 - 243339\cdot 2007 + 2494380\cdot 100\right)
= 1307223995$$

Since this upper bound $1307223995$ is achieved by $93$ $a_k$ equal to $20$ and $7$ $a_k$ equal to $21$. This is the maximum we seek.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the key insight from your solution is to come up with the number 5939, such that multiplying and summing over all powers of 2 generates 6021 =  3*2007. There is a pattern where people manage to generate the unknow part of the expression in this case $−3p_1x^2+2x^3$. I am struggling with these kinds of tricks I guess.